# JavaScript access from parent domain to subdomain?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

I've read that setting `document.domain = "example.com"` lets me access the parent domain from a subdomain.

Will the same work the other way around?

Let's say my main site is running under *http://example.com*. All API functions that I want to access via AJAX (GET & POST) are hosted on *http://**api**.example.com*.

Will I be able to access `api.example.com` from `example.com`?

**EDIT**: Looking at `document.domain` again, I don't think that this will solve the problem. The result from calls to ***api***.example.com are not necessary HTML, but output from a PHP script running on the API server. It can be JSON, plain text, etc. so there's no way to set `document.domain` for that (since it's not an iframe).

Comment: Simply configure your server so that all resources from `api.example.com` return this HTTP header: `Access-control-allow-origin: http://example.com`

Comment: Which is called Cross Origin Resource Sharing, or CORS for short.

Comment: Just a warning: CORS is not completely cross-browser yet, so you might be better off with JSONP for now.

Comment: @Casey Yes, IE6 and IE7. I hope OP doesn't have to support those...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set document.domain on BOTH pages

Alternatively set CORS headers on your server:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/

> A Quick Overview of CORS
>
> Firefox 3.5 and Safari 4 implement the
>   CORS specification, using
>   [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest) as an “API container”
>   that sends and receives the
>   appropriate headers on behalf of the
>   web developer, thus allowing
>   cross-site requests. IE8 implements
>   part of the CORS specification, using
>   [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx) as a similar “API
>   container” for CORS, enabling simple
>   cross-site GET and POST requests.
>   Notably, these browsers send the
>   ORIGIN header, which provides the
>   scheme (http:// or https://) and the
>   domain of the page that is making the
>   cross-site request. Server developers
>   have to ensure that they send the
>   right headers back, notably the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for
>   the ORIGIN in question (or ” * ” for
>   all domains, if the resource is
>   public) .
>
> The CORS standard works by adding new
>   HTTP headers that allow servers to
>   serve resources to permitted origin
>   domains. Browsers support these
>   headers and enforce the restrictions
>   they establish. Additionally, for HTTP
>   request methods that can cause
>   side-effects on user data (in
>   particular, for HTTP methods other
>   than GET, or for POST usage with
>   certain MIME types), the specification
>   mandates that browsers “preflight” the
>   request, soliciting supported methods
>   from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS
>   request header, and then, upon
>   “approval” from the server, sending
>   the actual request with the actual
>   HTTP request method. Servers can also
>   notify clients whether “credentials”
>   (including Cookies and HTTP
>   Authentication data) should be sent
>   with requests.

Comment: What if the page on api.example.com is not an HTML page, but text data returned from a PHP script?

Comment: IE 8 and later can do `XDomainRequest()`, too.

Comment: Yes, see the text: "IE8 implements part of the CORS specification, using XDomainRequest "

Comment: Guess you are not supporting IE7 if you selected this as an answer with CORS?

Comment: Actually I believe IE7 might still be happy if you add the server url to trusted sites

Comment: Should be noted that IE8 and IE9 do not send the cookies not even if credentials -> true .