# XSS Domain and Sub-domain

Tags: subdomain, xss, same-origin-policy

I want to access the resources of
**http://abc.example.com**
on
**http://example.com**.
Is this a violation of the **Same origin policy**?

I am not able to test it because I am designing something and do not have server access to validate the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277926/javascript-access-from-parent-domain-to-subdomain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript access from parent domain to subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277926/javascript-access-from-parent-domain-to-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you dont have server access, you can still test this. Set up a simple webserver on your laptop and modify your hosts file. Next lookup the definition of origin: Port, protocol and full hostname. Same origin  policy be relaxed by setting document.domain on subdomain or using CORS headers.